# Identify and print the starting number that creates the longest chain

Tags: ruby

I have this code so far:

```
def longest_awtz(n)
  upto = n
  series = []

  for x in 2..upto
    series << x
  end

  series.each do |num|
    print num.to_s + " - " 
    while num != 1
      if num % 2 == 0
        num = num / 2
        print num.to_s + " - "
      else
        num = (3 * num) + 1
        print num.to_s + " - "
      end
    end
    puts " "
  end
end

longest_awtz(6)
```

and the output of that code is:

```
---------------------------------------------
helloworld                                   
2 - 1 -                                      
3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  
4 - 2 - 1 -  
5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  
6 - 3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  
---------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to identify which starting number produces the longest chain , so I must put each chain in to an array and count it in order to identify which one is the longest. My final output must look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
helloworld                                   
2 - 1 -                                      
3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  
4 - 2 - 1 -  
5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  
6 - 3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 -  

[2,1]                 # has 2
[3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]   # has 8 
[4,2,1]               # has 3
[5,16,8,4,2,1]        # has 6
[6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1] # has 9
# identify and print the starting number that creates the longest chain.
6 is the starting number that creates the longest chain.
---------------------------------------------
```

So far, I have the first output above and I am stuck on how I can put each into an array. Can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: some link to the problem would be useful. It seems this is http://projecteuler.net/problem=14

Comment: Don't abuse bold and italics. They are for specific purposes. It does not make sense to have the entire text in bold face. Also, for you reference, English sentences start with a capital letter. And the first person pronoun is "I", not "i". You might have missed this in elementary school.

Comment: @sawa, Maybe the OP doesn't care what the grammar rules are, and the formatting is just an opportunity to express creativity?

Comment: @sawa , Sorry sawa for my mistake in grammar . I thought it is ok because this site is a site for those want to have a little  help in programming not an English grammar lesson site..

Comment: @nightStalkEr Good to have your reply. It is about politeness (My previous comment was meant to be ironical). If you expect people to read what you wrote, you should try to make it easier and comfortable for people to read. Especially, you are asking for help. People would not want to help you if you don't even put the effort to write the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first extract the generation of the sequence into its own method:

```
def generate_sequence(num)
  result = [num]
  while num != 1
    if num%2 == 0
      num = num/2
    else
      num = (3*num)+1
    end
    result << num
  end
  result
end
```

This will return an array containing the sequence. Then you can write a method that generates all series resulting from an input of `1..n`:

```
def generate_sequences_upto(n)
  1.upto(n).map do |num|
    generate_sequence(num)
  end
end
```

and another one to select the longest sequence:

```
def longest_sequence(n)
  generate_sequences_upto(n).max_by(&:length)
end
```

You can for example use it like this:

```
longest = longest_sequence(6)
puts "The longest sequence with length #{longest.length} is\n#{longest.inspect}"
```

It will output

```
The longest sequence with length 9 is
[6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

When you want to delimit the numbers with `" - "` i recommend the use of `Array#join`:

```
longest.join(' - ')
#=> "6 - 3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Project Euler problems (and all mathematical problems for that matter) are more concise and declarative if you use a [functional approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) with the appropiate abstractions:

```
collatz = proc { |n| n.even? ? n/2 : (3*n + 1) }
collatz_length = proc { |n| n > 1 ? 1 + collatz_length.(collatz.(n)) : 0 }
(1...1000).max_by(&collatz_length)
#=> 871
```

Comment: BTW: this is how I would have written that particular piece of code. I', just a big fan of point-free style as well as the 1.9 lambdas and the `.call` sugar :-) `collatz = ->n { if n.even? then n/2 else 3*n + 1 end }; collatz_length = ->n { if n > 1 then 1 + collatz_length.(collatz.(n)) else 0 end }; (1...1000).max_by(&collatz_length)`

Comment: @Jorg: Edited. `n.even?` -> I had forgotten this method. `max_by(&collatz_length)` -> of course! However, I hate (that's the word) the new 1.9 lambda syntax and the `proc.(args)` calls, so I am afraid I won't change that ;-)

Comment: +1, beautifully concise. Though I agree with @JörgWMittag on `.()` vs `[]` simply because the latter I always initially think is accessing a collection.

Comment: ok guys, you win, updated :-) for the record: what I don't like about the new notation is that it seems as if you forgot the write the method name...

Comment: I am just asking myself, why do we need the dot anyway? I would love to use parentheses without the dot, calling them like ay other method.

Comment: @padde: If you have a method `foo` which returns a `Proc`, then does `foo()` call the method `foo` and return the `Proc` or does it call the method `foo` and call the returned `Proc`? You don't know. It works in Python/ECMAScript etc., because they don't allow calling methods without parentheses, i.e. in the first case it would be `foo()` and in the second case it would be `foo()()`. Or, if you have a local variable called `foo` which contains a `Proc` and you have a method called `foo`, then what does `foo()` do?

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks, your example with the method returning a proc made it very clear!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `map`, as in

```
array = series.map do |num|
```

but to use this properly, you will need to adjust your block so that it returns the value of the array you want, not just print it out (`puts` returns `nil`, which you don't want here).

To collect each individual number into a sub-array inside the main one, instead of `puts`, you want `subarray.push( num )` or similar - there are a few equivalent syntaxes for this. Then instead (or after) `puts " "`, just have `subarray` variable (or whatever you have called it) at the end, which will make it the return value from the block, and add it to your main array. You will end up with an array of arrays.

If you want to explore what is possible with a Ruby object, I highly recommend starting up `irb` and using the `methods` command to see all the things you can do with it:

```
irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > a = [1,2,3,4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
1.9.3-p327 :002 > a.methods.sort
 => [:!, :!=, :!~, :&, :*, :+, :-, :<<, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :[], :[]=, :__id__, :__send__, :all?, :any?, :assoc, :at, :chunk, :class, :clear, :clone, :collect, :collect!, :collect_concat, :combination, :compact, :compact!, :concat, :count, :cycle, :define_singleton_method, :delete, :delete_at, :delete_if, :detect, :display, :drop, :drop_while, :dup, :each, :each_cons, :each_entry, :each_index, :each_slice, :each_with_index, :each_with_object, :empty?, :entries, :enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :fetch, :fill, :find, :find_all, :find_index, :first, :flat_map, :flatten, :flatten!, :freeze, :frozen?, :grep, :group_by, :hash, :include?, :index, :initialize_clone, :initialize_dup, :inject, :insert, :inspect, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :instance_of?, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :is_a?, :join, :keep_if, :kind_of?, :last, :length, :map, :map!, :max, :max_by, :member?, :method, :methods, :min, :min_by, :minmax, :minmax_by, :nil?, :none?, :object_id, :one?, :pack, :partition, :permutation, :pop, :private_methods, :product, :protected_methods, :public_method, :public_methods, :public_send, :push, :rassoc, :reduce, :reject, :reject!, :repeated_combination, :repeated_permutation, :replace, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :reverse, :reverse!, :reverse_each, :rindex, :rotate, :rotate!, :sample, :select, :select!, :send, :shift, :shuffle, :shuffle!, :singleton_class, :singleton_methods, :size, :slice, :slice!, :slice_before, :sort, :sort!, :sort_by, :sort_by!, :taint, :tainted?, :take, :take_while, :tap, :to_a, :to_ary, :to_enum, :to_s, :transpose, :trust, :uniq, :uniq!, :unshift, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :values_at, :zip, :|]
```

that's loads and loads of methods to learn! But if you type e.g. `Ruby Array map` into Google, you'll most often get a useful reference in the first answer.

Many Ruby idioms are based around things you can do by combining an array method with a block, it's worth spending time having an explore.